# Why are there so many Chrome processes?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome is doing four things. The browser itself, a GPU process, the tab for this website and one extension. So why are there eight chrome.exe processes?

Half of them don't even seem to be doing anything. Nothing crashes or malfunctions when they close. They just suck resources, apparently.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp3bV.png

Answer (score 1):

your question seems to be similar to [Why does Chrome has so many processes running, when I have just opened the application?](https://superuser.com/questions/1205231/why-does-chrome-has-so-many-processes-running-when-i-have-just-opened-the-appli) 
and also 
[Multiple chrome.exe processes in Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/174652/multiple-chrome-exe-processes-in-task-manager)

the TLDR version of those 2 post are...
Each Chrome Tab opens a fixed number of processes that are equal to the number of extensions.
so if 1 tab is open and you have 4 active extensions then you will have 4 Chrome Processes in your Windows Task Manager.
2 tabs will result in double that number; 8 processes listed in your Windows Task Manager.

So keeping a Tab in your background actually is using up resources.

To access your chrome Task Manager, click on the dots at the very end of your address bar; on the right hand side; 
Select More Tools and then Task Manager. That should show you what which Extension or Tab is taking up the most resources.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, while you might be well intentioned in your answer, if a question is a duplicate, it should simply be tagged as a duplicate and closed. Additionally, a lot of your question is based on links (which tend to disappear) so link-only answers are frowned on here. Past that, if you earn 50 rep a lot of what you have posted would be acceptable as a comment. But not as an answer.

Comment: @JakeGould As you say, a lot of this could be a comment.  I do realise that the 50 reps that need to split the trolls from the helpful, but isn't that really high ?
All we want to do is just be helpful. Is it a negative to be helpful ?
Also does the welcome page actually have a "how to on how to flag ?"

Comment: “I do realise that the 50 reps that need to split the trolls from the helpful, but isn't that really high ?” And lots of people earn that rep by contribution to the community by doing things like editing posts, posting decent answers and questions and such. “Is it a negative to be helpful ?” Yes, the negative discourages bad behavior that lowers the quality of posts in the community and further discourages copy cats. In this case you could have flagged this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This is in top google results and nevermind people whose negativity and excessive restrictive behaviour makes this community notorious.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed some chrome plugin, then it will use more resources of the CPU, and will show more number of process under Windows Task Manager >> Processes Tab