# Slack desktop app consumes almost 1GB only for 3 workspaces

Tags: windows-10, slack

Can you tell me why slack desktop app consumes almost `1GB` memory on my `Windows 10 Pro` PC? I have opened only 3 workspaces. This is horrible right? Any solution to reduce this.

This is the version: `Direct Download 3.3.3 64-bit`

[image]

This is the 3 workspaces:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desktop version of Slack is based on [Electron](https://electronjs.org/), which is basically standalone Chromium (open-source core of Google Chrome) plus some host OS integrations. In other words: it's a separate web browser, but limited to Slack.

Bad news: [Electron is a known resource hog](https://josephg.com/blog/electron-is-flash-for-the-desktop/). There is no way to fix it for you as a user. Slack developers are probably aware of this issue for some time now and they didn't fix it (and fixing it wouldn't be easy).

Good news: It's not really consuming 1 GB of RAM. Chromium's sandbox uses multiple processes that share some memory. So when simply summing per-process values, you're counting some memory areas multiple times. Still, it's probably using well over 500 MB.

One way to reduce Slack's memory consumption would be to use it in a browser instead of the standalone app.

Comment: Can you tell me why it shows `8 slacks` even though I have opened `3`?

Comment: See [Why does Chrome has so many processes running, when I have just opened the application?](https://superuser.com/a/1205250/194694)